# profit gets more with trailpoint

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i had searched more and more but didn't find any results and i hope to solve my problem ,,
I have an issue with Backtesting of tradingview  when i use Trail_offset and Trail_points
the profit in back test gets more and more than realtime for ex i set the Trail_points = 1%
and Trail_offset = 0.1%
the trade sent an alert to close with profit 0.9%
and when i see backtest it closed at candle close with 3%profit !
this leading to fake results
i searched many times about this problem but didn't find anything
if anyone could help me i will be very glad to him
and this is my code i am using

````
longtrail = input.float(title='Long trail (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.01) * close/syminfo.mintick 
longdev = input.float(title='Long Dev (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.001) * close/syminfo.mintick
STOPLOSS = input.float(title='STOP LOSS LONG (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.013) * close/syminfo.mintick 


if long
   strategy.entry(id='EL', direction=strategy.long, comment = message_long_entry)
   //alert("LONG ENTERZ", alert.freq_all)
float trail_pointss = longtrail
float trail_offsett = longdev
float losss = STOPLOSS

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
   strategy.exit(id='ELX', from_entry = 'EL', trail_points = trail_pointss, trail_offset = trail_offsett, loss= losss, comment = message_long_exit) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

this should get you on the right path.
working on a huge set of libraries right now. couple weeks ther will be a ton of toys to make scripting very quick and a few secret weapons.

https://www.tradingview.com/u/kaigouthro/#published-scripts

```
// my super handy function for making tickvalue distances..
 
_percent_in_ticks(x) =>    x * (close/syminfo.mintick)/100


profpcttrig        = input.float(1, ' prof pct trig %'              )
losspcttrig        = input.float(1, ' loss pct trig %'              )
trllosspctactivate = input.float(1, ' trl loss pct to activate'     )
trllosspctdist     = input.float(1, ' trl loss pct dist to follow'  )


///  long exit exqample -- make dupliaes, or invert the +/- /100 to reach desired price
_to_profit         = _percent_in_ticks(     profpcttrig             )  // no need to invert for short
_to_loss           = _percent_in_ticks(     losspcttrig             )  // no need to invert for short
_to_trail_points   = _percent_in_ticks(     trllosspctactivate      )  // no need to invert for short
_to_trail_offset   = _percent_in_ticks(     trllosspctdist          )

N = strategy.opentrades // to exit oldest trade first... or enter a number or track which trade you want to exit yourself..

_to_limit          = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(N)  * ( 1 + profpcttrig         /100)  // invert +/- for short
_to_stop           = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(N)  * ( 1 - losspcttrig         /100)  // invert +/- for short
_to_trail_price    = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(N)  * ( 1 - trllosspctactivate  /100)  // invert +/- for short


strategy.exit(
     id              =     'name_of_trade'
     from_entry      =     'name of open trade to close'
     qty             =     contracts                //  Number of contracts/shares/lots/units to exit a trade with.
     qty_percent     =     percexit                 //  Range from 0 to 100. If 'qty' is NaN, the default value of 'qty_percent' is 100.
     profit          =     _to_profit               //  Profit target >>>>  limit order whern ticks of profit is reached.
     limit           =     _to_limit                //  Profit target (requires a specific price). ('limit' is used instead of 'profit', if its value is specified).
     loss            =     _to_loss                 //  SL (ticks).        >> same rles as limit/prof, price overides ticks <<
     stop            =     _to_stop                 //  SL (price).        >> same rles as limit/prof, price overides ticks <<
     trail_points    =     _to_trail_points         //  Trail SL (tickls). >> same rles as limit/prof, price overides ticks <<
     trail_price     =     _to_trail_price          //  Trail SL (price).  >> same rles as limit/prof, price overides ticks <<
     trail_offset    =     _to_trail_offset         //  Trail DISTANCE (ticks).  HOW FAR WILL IT FOLLOW IT.
     comment         =     'comment'                //  Additional notes on the order.
     when            =     bool(ORDERPLACECONMD)  //  Condition of the order. .. when will it place the order (NOT TRRIGGER, .. PLACE)
     )
```

Comment: thanks for ur effort but when i put it in my code for exit condition it gives me  an  error at  "syntax error at input 'from_entry' 
and there is `when            =     bool(ORDERPLACECONMD)`
this Variable can i delete it or how can i define this variable in my code 
@kai-gouthro

Comment: erp... thyat's just there if you have something..  as in.. a bool command true or false for 'when'... as in >>>   close < open